# Converting Swift Array to NSData causes an error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsdata

I have two arrays

```
var questions: [Question]!
var types: [[Type]]!
```

I am trying to convert those two arrays to NSData. I do like below

```
let typesData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(types)
let questionsData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(questions)
```

As soon as it hits typesData, the app crashes and throws an error like following:

```
*** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x15e5a4100 of class '(app Name).Type' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead Unrecognized selector -[(app Name).Type replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
```

I am assuming it's causing an error since those arrays has custom types. Is there any way I can convert those arrays to NSData? Any solutions for solving this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Do Question and Type implements initWithCoder:?

Comment: seems like u need to implements NSCoding for them then only u can save it as NSData

Comment: @Larme, they do not have initWithCoder function. Do I need to implement it?

Comment: @Tj3n, A bit more info would be appreciated

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For swift, you need to implement this in your Object (Question, Type) class like so:

```
class ItemObject:NSObject, NSCoding {
    var itemName = ""
    var itemCheck = false

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(itemName, forKey:"itemName")
        aCoder.encodeBool(itemCheck, forKey:"itemCheck")
    }


    required init (coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.itemName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("itemName") as! String
        self.itemCheck = aDecoder.decodeBoolForKey("itemCheck")
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

This is also required for store custom object to `NSUserDefaults` and `CoreData`